# Creating an Image view of given shape in android

Tags: android, imageview, crop

[image]

I need to create an imageview of this particular shape in Android. If cropping an image in this shape is possible, then also its fine. Please help me out with it?

Comment: You need to do your level of customization for reference use this link https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview

Comment: and have you tried something ? atlease google or anything ?

Comment: Yeah i think @AnjaliTripathi is right, you can see one of the function [Bitmap Mask Based ImageViews](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview#bitmap-mask-based-imageviews) in [android-shape-imageview](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview). So what you should do is provide a shape and a whole photo, and then you can get the picture you want.

Comment: Simple solution. Why don't you make that part of image transparent ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be the complete set

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/gohan" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/triangle_shape" />
</FrameLayout>
```

> triangle_shape.xml this will be inside your `drawable` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="-70" // you will have to tweak this a little for adjustment
            android:pivotX="100%"
            android:pivotY="75%"
            android:toDegrees="40">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <stroke
                    android:width="10dp"
                    android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
                <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_blue_bright" />
            </shape>
        </rotate>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Output
[image: gohan]