# Crop Image with shape

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

Is there any way to set  images in the imageViews like this? Each imageView is clickable and those couldn't overlapped with each other.

I saw this answer [Creating an Image view of a given shape in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34759931/creating-an-image-view-of-given-shape-in-android)
 , but it's not what I want, because the imagViews are fitted to parent's width and height and one of the imageViews is a shape and not accepted drawable images.

[image]